# ReRegisterForFinalize SuppressFinalize real life example

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, suppressfinalize

I was just reading this article,
“[Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](https://web.archive.org/web/20130418095110/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985010.aspx)”, by Jeffrey Richter, and I couldn't think of any real life sample for using `ReRegisterForFinalize` or `SuppressFinalize`.

Could anyone provide me with some examples?

Comment: `SuppressFinalize` is common, but no idea when I'd want to use `ReRegisterForFinalize`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A handful of places it gets used in the .NET framework, always a good place to look.  Basic patterns are:

- a disposed object gets reused.  The Dispose() method has called SuppressFinalize so it needs to be re-registered (NativeWindow, RequestContextBase, TaskExceptionHolder class)
- the finalizer failed and caught an exception.  Little to do but to retry later.  That code is wrapped with if (!Environment.HasShutdownStarted && !AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsFinalizingForUnload()) to make sure that doing this makes sense (DynamicResolver and LoaderAllocatorScout class)
- the object participates in a caching scheme and gets re-cached (OverlappedData class)

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of `IDisposable` often requires `SuppressFinalize`: look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx) for the code.

I don't have a good example on `ReRegisterForFinalize` now.

Comment: OK 'SuppressFinalize' looks pretty strait-forward, after reading those samples. prevent the costly finalize method to be called if I dipspoed the object by myself.

Answer (score 1):

You need `ReRegisterForFinalize` when resurrecting an instance. Resurrection (mentioned in the linked article) is the action of re-rooting an object from its destructor (finalizer).

That only moves the question to "when would you resurrect an object". In my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3680281/60761) I speculated that a connectionpool or similar construct might use it.

Comment: I still have no idea when would I want to use `ReRegisterForFinalize `

Comment: In 'normal' application or library code you wouldn't. A ConnectionPool is a highly specialized piece of software.